# How to disable beep sound in Vagrant Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I'm using Ubuntu in Vagrant and connect by `ssh` from Windows host.

I want to disable beep sound when I'm using bash in Ubuntu.

To disable beep sound I set the this restry key.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Sound]
"Beep"="no"
```

And I try to remove `pcspkr` module in Ubuntu, but it's not installed from first place.

```
$ sudo modprobe -r pcspkr
modprobe: FATAL: Module pcspkr not found.
```

I'm using `ConEmu` as a console, but in the setting there is no beep sound option.

What can I do to disable beep sound?

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/turn-off-beep-in-bash-shell-440305/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I add `setterm -blength 0` to `~/.bashrc` and load it by `. ~/.bashrc`, but beep sound still active.

Comment: Thought you need to do that on both client and server. However I'm not a ssh-guru and my suggestion may be incorrect )